# Reusing popped fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Lets look on this picture:

[image: fragmentA->FragmentB]

In Android tutorial every time when `FragmentA` is replaced with `FragmentB` new instance of `FragmentB` is created.

Lets look next case `FragmentA` to `FragmentB` then back (press) to `FragmentA` and again go to `FragmentB`. Maybe if old instance of `FragmentB` still alive would be better use it (only updating data) instead of create new instance? Is there any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using fragmentTransaction.show method to re-use existing fragment.

Use following method to switch fragment, it will show fragment if it is already added.

```
public void switchFragment (Fragment oldFragment, Fragment newFragment, int frameId) {

    boolean addFragment = true;

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();
    String tag = newFragment.getArguments ().getString (BaseFragment.TAG);
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag (tag);

    // Check if fragment is already added
    if (fragment != null && fragment.isAdded ()) {
        addFragment = false;
    }

    // Hide previous fragment
    String oldFragmentTag = oldFragment.getArguments ().getString (BaseFragment.TAG);

    if (!tag.equals (oldFragmentTag)) {
        FragmentTransaction hideTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();
        Fragment fragment1 = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag (oldFragmentTag);
        hideTransaction.hide (fragment1);
        hideTransaction.commit ();
    }

    // Add new fragment and show it
    FragmentTransaction addTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();

    if (addFragment) {
        addTransaction.add (frameId, newFragment, tag);
        addTransaction.addToBackStack (tag);
    }
    else {
        newFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag (tag);
    }

    addTransaction.show (newFragment);

    addTransaction.commit ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple Singleton for your fragment,

```
public class FragmentGoogleMap extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

MapView mapView;
GoogleMap googleMap;

private static FragmentGoogleMap instance = null;

private FragmentGoogleMap() {
}

public static FragmentGoogleMap getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new FragmentGoogleMap();
    }
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

frome activity you can get instance

```
private FragmentGoogleMap fragmentGoogleMap;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentGoogleMap = FragmentGoogleMap.getInstance();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_map_container,fragmentGoogleMap).commit();

}
```